# kinematics question involving velocity and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle starts moving rectilinearly at time ${t = 0}$ such that its velocity '${v}$'
changes with time '${t}$' according to the equation ${v = at^{2} - bt}$ where ${t }$ is in seconds and ${v}$ in ${m/s}$ . The time for which particles retards is

> (i)${t < 1/2}$
>   (ii)${1/2 < t <1}$
>   (iii) ${ t > 1}$
>   (iv)${t < 1/2}$  and  ${t > 1}$

I am unable to calculate the time of retardation from the given information.
(I am a beginner in calculus so I want just a hint for mathematical calculation of a retardation time.)

So how I can approach this problem?

Comment: Retarding = negatively accelerating (i.e decelerating)

Comment: Your equation v = t^2 - t (where t is in seconds and v in m/s) is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: But that's the question.

Comment: @pranjal verma To be correct, $v = at^2 + bt$ to account for the dimensions... but regardless the question can still be answered if you just naively use the given v(t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A retarding motion is one in which $a = dv/dt <0$. You are given $v=v(t)$ so simply sketch the graph and find the region in which the derivative is negative.